# Does fodder last forever?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

I planted some grass for fodder. Right now I have a lot of sunny days, so my cow can eat outside. I just store the fodder in my storage, and I am building a nice pile of it, which I use on rainy days. That is all well and good, but I also have a nice stockpile.

Will it last forever so I can use it when grass doesn't grow, so I don't have to buy food for my cow from the surly animal handler dude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am now into Fall of the first year.  The Fodder I have in my Storage has not degraded at all; without quality levels, the only option available to it is to disappear.

Fun fact: Fodder inside a Barn is worth more than when your animals are outside; when eaten directly from the field, Fodder is good for a single animal.  Inside the Barn, though, each Fodder is good for ~5 servings; if you don't have enough animals to eat it all, it will stay in the trough until it gets eaten.

Comment: i should comment that you can stack the fodder in the same tray to make it last longer and you can fill up all the trays plus they wont expire so you can stack up the feed for your animals, also, considering the effect of gold watering cans and scythes and it grows back the day after you can mass produce it and sell off the access